# ¿Porqué está fallando la herencia de los formularios?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Desde el día de ayer estoy teniendo problemas con la herencia que existe entre los diferentes formularios de un proyecto. Parece que luego de una actualización de Windows algo se ha dañado en el VS, porque todo el proyecto que estuvo funcionando correctamente ha empezado a fallar.

Al abrir un formulario en VB estoy teniendo este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para descartar el problema, he creado un nuevo formulario base para usarlo como origen de la herencia, sin embargo el error es el mismo.

Cuando compilo los proyectos no muestra ningún error, pero al tratar de ejecutarlo aparece la conocida imagen de que hay errores en la construcción y si quiero utilizar una versión anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015 Community y Windows 10 Versión 1909.

Si alguno de ustedes ha tenido el mismo problema luego de hacer un Windows Update y ha logrado resolverlo, por favor me comenta.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: El error esta bien especificado. No es capaz de cargar `SistemaIntegrado.FormBase`. Es posible que te falte alguna referencia? A lo mejor esa clase está en otro proyecto con una version objetivo de net framework diferente?

Comment: Justamente he estado revisando las referencias asociadas y he cambiado a net framework 4.0, estaba apuntando a net framework 2.0 ya que es un proyecto muy antiguo. Estoy teniendo algunos warnings que estoy tratando de resolver, pero al menos los formularios ya se pueden ver.